# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: sql-server, wcf, filestream

I am trying to generate a report by using SQL Server 2008 R2 File Stream and WCF Service. I am able to generate reports if the service is hosted in the same server which database is located i.e. Database and service is hosted in the same server.

If I hosted the service in different server I am getting the "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the path specified" exception. I have given all the necessary permissions to the SQL FileStream share location like IIS_User, Everyone etc and I am able to access the share path from the new server also. Still getting the same error.

When I am checking EventViewer in server it is throwing, System can not find the specified path
\\Machine_Name\FolderName\v1\DBNAme\dbo\TableName\ColumName\06E9456C-A090-24Ge-9C35-25FDG54FE78RR25

\\Machine_Name\FolderName\ this one is SQL FileStream share path.

Please help me to get out this.

Comment: I think it may be a permission issue, how do you host the WCF service?

Comment: Hosted on IIS 10 and tried with impersonate, App_Pool  running user is added to the Database and given Read/Write permissions. In WCF service used Integrated Security = True to connect databse. The WCF service hosted in Windows 2016 server and the Database is 2008 R2 and both are different servers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issues like this are related to any of the following need to be looked at:

1. firewall settings from the web server to the database server.
2. connection string errors.
3. enable the appropriate protocol pipes/ tcp-ip.

You could refer to the following article to troubleshoot Connecting to the SQL Server Database Engine:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

This content comes from this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx).

In my opinion, this is likely to be caused by a connection string error, you need to check your connection string.